# Get Assembly Version of DLL using TFS Build Tasks

Tags: tfs

Is there any way to read the assembly version of a file using TFS Build Tasks or Build Definitions.

I want to build an InstallShield Project in TFS using build tasks.  I am able to build it but in order to pass the Product Version to InstallShield I need some mechanism to read it from the assembly (we are considering assembly version for MSI or setup as Product Version).

Answer (score 1):

The [MSBuildExtensionsPack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/) has an [Assembly task](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/3.5.10.0/html/2610c1b7-348a-901e-3c90-84a3deb99c38.htm#exampleToggle) you can use for this purpose.